# how to add a bar specifying number of each color in a colored matrix in matlab?

Tags: matlab, matlab-figure

i have a matrix that i  colored   in green/blue/white according to the values in the cell of each matrix (1-green , 2-blue  ,   0-white)

i want to add a bar to the graph that specifys how much green and blue cells there are.

this is  how i colored the  matrix :

```
figure;
hp = pcolor(padarray(MY_MATRIX(:,:,1),[1 1],'replicate','post'));
hp.EdgeColor = [0 0 0];
hp.LineWidth = 2;
colormap([1 1 1;0 1 0;0 0 1;]);
```

i want to have something like this maybe:

green-25

blue-13

thank you in  advance.

Comment: Does [histogram](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/matlab.graphics.chart.primitive.histogram.html) do what you want?

Comment: i don't know   how to count the specific number of green cells for example and add them to the already colored matrix

Comment: i can calculate the number of greenc cells in the matrix  using loop  where i loop on MY_MATRIX and calculate how many green  cells are there , but after that how can i add this valuse to the graph ina bar

Comment: because green cells  are basically cells with value 1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[subplot](https://ww2.mathworks.cn/help/matlab/ref/subplot.html?lang=en) and [bar](https://ww2.mathworks.cn/help/matlab/ref/bar.html?lang=en). (histogram works 10/10 but bars are easier to tinker with)

```
% MY_MATRIX=randi(3,5,5)-1;
figure;
subplot(1,2,1)
hp = pcolor(padarray(MY_MATRIX(:,:,1),[1 1],'replicate','post'));
hp.EdgeColor = [0 0 0];
hp.LineWidth = 2;
colormap([1 1 1;0 1 0;0 0 1;]);

subplot(1,2,2)
bh=bar(diag([nnz(MY_MATRIX(:)==1),nnz(MY_MATRIX(:)==2)]),'stacked','FaceColor','g');
bh(2).FaceColor='b';
```

[image]